# when i create a user for rabbitmq-management， an error has occured

Tags: rabbitmq

when i create a user for rabbitmq

```
[root@localhost ~]# rabbitmqctl add_user admin admin
```

an error has occured,message:

```
Creating user "admin"
Error: {undef,
           [{crypto,hash,[sha256,<<165,63,157,75,97,100,109,105,110>>],[]},
            {rabbit_password,hash,2,
                [{file,"src/rabbit_password.erl"},{line,34}]},
            {rabbit_auth_backend_internal,add_user_sans_validation,2,
                [{file,"src/rabbit_auth_backend_internal.erl"},{line,191}]},
            {rpc,'-handle_call_call/6-fun-0-',5,
                [{file,"rpc.erl"},{line,205}]}]}
```

And I found there isn't default user [guest]

```
[root@localhost ~]# rabbitmqctl list_users
Listing users
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{undef,[{crypto,` means that your Erlang installation is not completed.
The crypto library is missing.

if you are using Centos I suggest using this Zero dependency package: https://github.com/rabbitmq/erlang-rpm/releases/tag/v19.3.6.2

Or try to execute `yum install erlang-crypto`

if you are Debian  try with `apt-get install erlang-crypto`

Comment: thank you so much! I try to install the zero dependency package. It's useful