# Not able to add user to RabbitMQ using add_user command

Tags: rabbitmq

I use the below command to add a user to RabbitMQ

```
rabbitmqctl add_user heartbeat alive
```

I get the below error

```
Adding user "heartbeat" ...
Error:
{:undef, [{:crypto, :hash, [:sha256, <<94, 223, 167, 31, 97, 108, 105, 118, 101>>], []}, {:rabbit_password, :hash, 2, [file: 'src/rabbit_password.erl', line: 34]}, {:rabbit_auth_backend_internal, :add_user_sans_validation, 3, [file: 'src/rabbit_auth_backend_internal.erl', line: 252]}, {:rpc, :"-handle_call_call/6-fun-0-", 5, [file: 'rpc.erl', line: 197]}]}
```

What wrong I am doing here and I am not able to understand the error.

RabbitMQ server version is 3.7.7

Comment: I found an answer to this question from this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45605459/when-i-create-a-user-for-rabbitmq-management-an-error-has-occured

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It resolved on mac os using the below command.

```
brew install openssl
```